# Insert formula into cells return '#NAME?'

Tags: excel, vb6, excel-formula

I have a problem with the insert of a formula in Excel.

[image: Error formula]

As you can see once the excel is generate, the formula is in this format ('#NOME?') , but it is correct! Clicking on it with the mouse in fact you see the correct formula.

To enter the formula I do this:

```
xlsSheet.Cells(5, 5) = "=SOMMA(H1:H7)"
```

Is there another way?

Comment: perhaps it needs the English name `Sum` instead of `Somma`? So `=Sum(H1:H7)` or `=Sum(E7:E24)` (using both your examples)

Comment: I will make that the answer, so you mark it as answered so others will benefit if they come across this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula needs to be written with the **English** name `Sum`.

So `=Sum(H1:H17)` for example.